# Problem: After using org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter, pages have no PDAcroForm

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using the below code to split a tax form **PDF** into individual pages. When using the resulting individual pages, no **PDAcroForm** is found on the pages.

Is this a limitation?

What am I missing?

```
package xxxx.util.pdf.box;

import org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PdfSplitter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER
        = Logger.getLogger( PdfSplitter.class.getSimpleName( ) );

    public static List<byte[]> splitPdfBytes(
        byte[] pdfBytes
    ) {

        List<byte[]> pages = new ArrayList<>( );

        try (
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load( pdfBytes );
        ) {

            Splitter splitter = new Splitter();

            List<PDDocument> docs = splitter.split( document );

            for ( PDDocument doc : docs ) {

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );

                doc.save( baos );

                pages.add( baos.toByteArray( ) );

            }

        } catch ( IOException e ) {

            LOGGER.severe( e.getMessage( ) );

        }

        return pages;

    }

}
```

Later on:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(templateStream)

PDDocumentCatalog pdDocCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();

PDAcroForm acroForm = pdDocCatalog.getAcroForm();

// acroForm is null !
```

Are there options in the splitter class I should be taking advantage of?

---

UPDATE 08/25/2022:

Thank you for informing me of this limitation.

The use case is as follows:

The IRS supplies Forms 1099 in 1 pdf file with each copy or page. For example, see https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1099div.pdf

My app fills out the recipient copy of the form So I only want page 4 of the PDF.

To work around this limitation, I am filling out the PDF first using AcroForm/AcroField population and then removing the pages I don’t need.

Comment: Yes it's a known limitation. Adding it would be quite a lot of work because of corner cases where a field appears on several pages. I also doubt that there would be a use case - why split a tax form?!

Comment: Re your "answer" (which will likely be deleted soon), you could also fill, flatten, and then delete the pages you don't need, assuming you want to print.